# SQL Server sort slow with many common values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I have a view of invoices that brings in customer name, things like that.

There are a few million rows here over a few hundred customers.  The view is lightning fast - but if I add a sort on Customer Name it takes a while to load (like 3000ms compared to 5ms).

The query joins Invoice to Customer, then sorts by Customer Name then by order number.

I understand why - just wondering if there are any tricks for improving the sort speed?

Comment: Do you have an index on the Customer Name column?

Comment: If this is in association with some application, it might be faster to sort the query results with your application code.

Comment: I have tried it with and without -- it doesn't really help because it has to compare every invoice to each other because the customers name is the same.  The index doesn't help because that's not the bottleneck.  I could optimize for this specific scenario, but I want to support dynamic sorting.

Comment: There are millions of rows, so it won't be faster to sort in application code.  It takes way longer to return the full data set.

Comment: What, you mean [you don't buy this advice (tip #2)](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/02/7-things-developers-should-know-about-sql-server/)? :-)

Comment: No, I don't.  If you have a grid that supports dynamic compound sorting, you can't figure it out in the app - especially with paging.  Also - it's not feasible to load it all into memory.  The query takes ~30 seconds to load all data without doing a TOP N.  I am a fan of Mr. Ozar - but I'm not concerned about our SQL CPU's at this point.

Comment: I know, that specific one was a head-scratcher for me too. I can see that there are definitely very narrow use cases where that advice may work out, but for the vast majority of cases it can't possibly be better. To be clear, I was being cheeky.

Comment: Interesting opinion though - it's a good read.  Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

You could add an index on the customer id/name.

You could partition by the table by customer.

The `order by` is going to take a long time, because -- without an index -- it has to read all the data.  If you use and index or table partition, then you can get the rows without reading the entire table.

To elaborate on the index.  There are two considerations.  The first is whether you are selecting all the rows or only a few.  An index will definitely help the time to first record returned, in most cases.

The second consideration is whether the index helps in fetching all the records.  The question here is selectivity.  If a data page in the invoice table has several hundred records, and there are only several hundred customers, then the index will not help.  On average, each page would have each customer.

If a data page has only a few dozen invoices, then, on average, only one page in about ten would have a given customers invoice -- and, voila, the index would reduce the I/O from a full table scan by a factor of about 10.  (There are other considerations, such as read-ahead but I'm skipping those.)

You don't provide enough information about the system and table structure for a definitive answer, but an index might be useful.

Comment: Neither indexing or partitioning will help in this scenario.

Comment: @Adam . . . Why don't you think so?  It should do an index scan to get the row ids.  This will definitely help on getting the first row returned.  Even if the view needs to return all the rows or not, a few hundred customers might be sufficiently selective.

Comment: Wasn't my down-vote btw, I up-voted. May not be useful to the OP but may very well be useful for other readers with a similar problem.

Comment: I don't think there's anything I can do. The reason I don't think an index would help is because I've tried it with an index.  Sorting by CustomerName exclusively isn't too slow... Add CustomerName, OrderNumber -- then it gets slow.  Ordering by OrderNumber is fine too, it's the compound sort (My initial description was lacking this detail - my apologies).

Comment: @Adam . . . Was your index on CustomerName or CustomerName *and* OrderNumber?

Comment: Order Number is in a different table - but yes it is indexed.

Comment: I think my solution will be changing the application :) I will just make the customer pre-set with a "none" option -- that way the load is quick unless someone needs to order without any criteria.